# Mapping a table with value from other table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "Codes" with below data

```
code1 |code2 |code3 |code4 |
A     |  C   |    A |    B |
B     |  A   |    B |    C |
C     |  C   |    A |    B |
```

And I have another table

```
code | number |
A    |  1     |
B    |  2     |
C    |  3     |
```

My output should be decoded as :

```
code1 |code2 |code3 |code4 |
1     |  3   |    1 |    2 |
2     |  1   |    2 |    3 |
3     |  3   |    1 |    2 |
```

Please help me in solving this

Comment: What did you try to achieve that? **Hint:** `INNER JOIN`. Btw, seems very bad design.

Comment: HINT: SO is not a **free coding resource** we help you fix code YOU have written, we **dont** write it for you

Comment: I dont know which join I have to use to solve this.. And also should I use all the columns in the join condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple INNER JOIN to get the result, 
Use this following code

Table Names : codes, number

```
select B.number,C.number,D.number,E.number from codes A 
INNER JOIN number B on A.code1=B.code 
INNER JOIN number C on A.code2=C.code 
INNER JOIN number D on A.code3=D.code 
INNER JOIN number E on A.code4=E.code
```